# How to automatically resize a child element in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I am making the GUI of my software with QT Designer.

My GUI has some tabs which I successfully managed to auto-resize in full width when the user makes fullscreen the GUI on his computer.

Then inside each tab, I need to insert a Toolbox. But this time, I didn't succeed in auto-resize this toolbox when the user makes the GUI full screen.

I think the best way to explain to you my issue is to have a look at my screenshots:
My GUI in QT designer:

[image]

The preview with the issue:

[image]

You can see on the preview that the toolbox is keeping the same size when I go for fullscreen.

Comment: Add a layout to `tab_Run`

Comment: Thanks for helping, but after I added a layout, it is now the layout which doesn't auto resize. So the problem stay the same. see http://prntscr.com/v7seds and http://prntscr.com/v7sewh  Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Each widget should have a layout. Add a layout to the `groupbox`

Comment: it doesn't change anything. I still have the same issue. It is a nightmare to make such an easy thing.

Comment: Once you understand how layouts work it is very simple to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

You need to add a layout to `tab_Run`, e.g. by selecting `tabWidget` and pressing `Ctrl+L` (on Windows), so your tree would look like this:

[image: Objects tree]

**Note:** In general, you have to set a layout for every widget, the size of whos children you want to be managed automatically by Qt.

### Example

As a reference, here is the `ui`-file I have created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_Run">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Run</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="QToolBox" name="toolBox">
          <property name="currentIndex">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="page">
           <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
             <x>0</x>
             <y>0</y>
             <width>758</width>
             <height>443</height>
            </rect>
           </property>
           <attribute name="label">
            <string>Page 1</string>
           </attribute>
          </widget>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="page_2">
           <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
             <x>0</x>
             <y>0</y>
             <width>758</width>
             <height>443</height>
            </rect>
           </property>
           <attribute name="label">
            <string>Page 2</string>
           </attribute>
          </widget>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_Campaigns">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Campaigns</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_Settings">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Settings</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_Help">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Help</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

### Result

Here is the produced result:

[image: App Window]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Can you explain how do you add a layout? I tried to reproduce exactly what you've done, but I can't. Also, can you please show your result in the full screen as it was my original question?

Comment: @GauthierButtez, I have edited my answer. Please take a look. As for the fullscreen result, I do not understand what you mean. The result, which is shown, is the whole application window.

Comment: If it would be the full screen window, we could see this icon on the window http://prntscr.com/v7twqi . THis is not the case, you are not in full screen.

Comment: I don't know how this could help you further, but since you insist, here it is: [maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br9Cq.png).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The ctrl + L doesn't work from my side. Don't you mind to send me your UI file? I think it will be easier.